# How to calculate the size of text depending on the amount of blocks dividing the text to and opposite?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

In the textBoxSplitAmount I enter digits for example 12 this meaning the text I paste into the richTextBoxToSplit should be splitted equal to 12 blocks of text. and if for example I enter in the textBox 111111 then it should divide the text to 111111 equal blocks.

I added a new label name lblSizeInfo that display the size of the whole text inside the richTextBoxToSplit and also displaying the size of each block depending the number of blocks I entered in the textBox or also depending on how much text I paste into the richTextBox in both cases it's calculating the sizes and display them.

The problem is for example if i I paste a text into the richTextBox and the size of the text is:  481 bytes and the amount of each block is 12 so each block size is 72 bytes but then I change in the textBox the number of blocks to 11111111 now it's showing each block size to be 63.58 MB but that's not possible because the whole text size is only 481 bytes.

where is the bug in my calculation logic?

[image: calculation of size is wrong]

I'm not sure what to do in that case? first how to make the calculation to be right? and second should I avoid somehow from the user to be able to enter so long numbers like 11111111? maybe I should limit the number of possible blocks the text can be dividing to?

update method:

```
private void UpdateSplitButtonState()
{
    // Check if the text box is empty or contains only '0'
    bool isTextBoxEmptyOrZero = string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxSplitAmount.Text) || textBoxSplitAmount.Text.All(c => c == '0');

    // Check if the rich text box is empty
    bool isRichTextBoxEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBoxToSplit.Text);

    // Enable the "Split" button only if both conditions are met
    btnSplit.Enabled = !(isTextBoxEmptyOrZero || isRichTextBoxEmpty);

    // Calculate and display size information
    if (!isRichTextBoxEmpty && !isTextBoxEmptyOrZero)
    {
        int textSizeInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(richTextBoxToSplit.Text);
        int blockSize = int.Parse(textBoxSplitAmount.Text);

        if (blockSize > 0 && richTextBoxToSplit.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            long blockSizeInBytes = blockSize * Encoding.UTF8.GetMaxByteCount(1);
            lblSizeInfo.Text = FormatSizeInfo(textSizeInBytes) + ", Block Size: " + FormatSizeInfo(blockSizeInBytes);
        }
        else
        {
            lblSizeInfo.Text = "";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblSizeInfo.Text = ""; // Clear the label if the rich text box is empty or blockSize is zero
    }
}
```

and the format method:

```
private string FormatSizeInfo(long sizeInBytes)
{
    const long KB = 1024;
    const long MB = 1024 * KB;
    const long GB = 1024 * MB;

    if (sizeInBytes >= GB)
    {
        double sizeInGB = (double)sizeInBytes / GB;
        return string.Format("{0:F2} GB", sizeInGB);
    }
    else if (sizeInBytes >= MB)
    {
        double sizeInMB = (double)sizeInBytes / MB;
        return string.Format("{0:F2} MB", sizeInMB);
    }
    else if (sizeInBytes >= KB)
    {
        double sizeInKB = (double)sizeInBytes / KB;
        return string.Format("{0:F2} KB", sizeInKB);
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Format("{0} bytes", sizeInBytes);
    }
}
```

the richtextobx textchanged event:

```
private void richTextBoxToSplit_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateSplitButtonState();
}
```

the textBoxSplitAmount textchanged event:

```
private void textBoxSplitAmount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateSplitButtonState();
}
```

key press:

```
private void textBoxSplitAmount_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true; // Ignore the key press if it's not a digit or a control character (e.g., Backspace)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you divide 481 bytes in 12 blocks, the result should be 40 bytes, not 72 bytes, so your logic is not working even for your original example.

The fault in your logic is in the method `UpdateSplitButtonState`, in the line:

```
long blockSizeInBytes = blockSize * Encoding.UTF8.GetMaxByteCount(1);
```

you should be dividing the total bytes by the amount of blocks, but you are multiplying `blockSize` by `Encoding.UTF8.GetMaxByteCount(1)`, which is always 1. What's the purpose of `Encoding.UTF8.GetMaxByteCount(1)` here?

More importantly, you should rename the variable `blockSize` to `amountOfBlocks`. As it is right now, it is very misleading because the value that you input in the textbox is supposed to be the amount of blocks, not the size of each block, if I understood your question correctly. Once you have the length of your text (in bytes) and the amount of blocks, calculate the size of each block (in bytes) by a division:

```
long blockSizeInBytes = textSizeInBytes / amountOfBlocks;
```

Inside the conditional block `if (!isRichTextBoxEmpty && !isTextBoxEmptyOrZero){ }`, update the code like this:

```
int textSizeInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(richTextBoxToSplit.Text);
int amountOfBlocks = int.Parse(textBoxSplitAmount.Text);

if (amountOfBlocks > 0 && textSizeInBytes > 0)
    {
        long blockSizeInBytes = textSizeInBytes / amountOfBlocks;
        lblSizeInfo.Text = FormatSizeInfo(textSizeInBytes) + ", Block Size: " + FormatSizeInfo(blockSizeInBytes);
    }
    else
    {
        lblSizeInfo.Text = "";
    }
}
```

> should I avoid somehow from the user to be able to enter so long
> numbers like 11111111? maybe I should limit the number of possible
> blocks the text can be dividing to?

In order to limit the amount blocks the user can input, you need to take into account the actual length of the text. For example, if the length is 10 characters, then your maximum amount of blocks will be 10, but if your text is 1000 characters, then you can input in the textbox up to 1000.

First, inside the class Form1, add a private field ´´´previousAmountOfBlocks´´´ to keep track of the previous textBox value once you change it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int previousAmountOfBlocks = 0;
    
    // the rest of the class code continues...
}
```

Then, update again the logic inside the conditional `if (!isRichTextBoxEmpty && !isTextBoxEmptyOrZero){ }` like this:

```
int textSizeInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(richTextBoxToSplit.Text);
var amountOfBlocks = int.Parse(textBoxSplitAmount.Text);

if (amountOfBlocks > 0 && textSizeInBytes > 0)
{
    long blockSizeInBytes = textSizeInBytes / amountOfBlocks;

    // if the result of the division is < 1, the amount of blocks is
    // too large for the current text size so we set the
    // textbox value to the previous value and return
    if (blockSizeInBytes < 1)
    {
        textBoxSplitAmount.Text = previousAmountOfBlocks.ToString();
                   
        return;
    }

    lblSizeInfo.Text = FormatSizeInfo(textSizeInBytes) + ", Block Size: " + FormatSizeInfo(blockSizeInBytes);

    // update the previousAmountOfBlocks to the current, accepted value
    previousAmountOfBlocks = amountOfBlocks;
}
```

Comment: @Jones please see my answer again. I updated the last part so you can limit the number that the User inputs into the textbox as per your requirements